# HTML5 navigation app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

currently we target ios devices with an ipad/iphone app. Am looking into this week prototyping the equivalent of the app in html5. The current ios app is a navigation app.

My question is, is there a way to make a navigation based html5 app? i.e. user hits www.mypage.com, they get the starting navigation page, they than click on a button on the starting control which slides a new control in from the right, on the new control there is a back button and when this is clicked the starting navigation page slides back into focus. All this happens while staying on the www.mypage.com link, it is really just one page and user controls are just moved in and out of the page.

Is this possible? If so is there any examples out there of this? Im a MS programmer at heart so am looking at doing this on asp.net mvc with html5.

Cheers.

Comment: as an ms programmer you'll be disappointed that most html5 advanced api are not supported in ie<9 (and ie9 isn't so good at that either)

Comment: @alonisser, the OP said that he is targeting iOS devices so he won't be disappointed since he wouldn't care about IE.

Comment: We currently provide two seperate solutions. One to target the desktop (currently a winforms app) and one to target mobile devices (universal ios app). Being that our client base (99% of them anyway) are all mobile on apple devices our quickest way to get an enterprise solution onto those devices was to go down the ios app path. Im hoping to make a HTML5 website/app that will handle both our desktop and mobile end points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) will do exactly what you need.  Single page web app, transitions and a powerful JQueryUI like theme roller etc.

As an aside ASP.NET MVC 4 will have JQuery Mobile support "built in" and if you want to try out either get the latest Web PI for Mvc and JQueryMobile is up on NuGet

Comment: Thanks for your response Daz. As stated in the comments above, we dont just want to target mobile devices with this solution, want to cover all. And also want to leverage other functionality of html5

Comment: @raven this kind of navigation is more suitable to mobile, but with some css hacks jquery mobile is also relevant for desktop. again - there is a lot of functionality under the html5 title - please refrine what are you looking for(geolocation? web sockets? history api? web workers? drawing with canvas?local storage/indexdb? css3 effects?). jquery mobile gives you the navigation it has nothing to do with html5

Comment: @alonisser JQueryMobile is an entirely HTML5 based framework.  All of the markup uses HTML5 semantics and the page navigation system uses Custom Data Attibutes (data-*).

Comment: @daz lewis - Jquery mobile is using html5, but as I pointed to raven it is more about smart mobile Ui and capturing mobile events than about being an html5 showcase. html5 is big name that includes many js api,semantics,ui, browser rendering framework etc